# Where can I get HighStock old versions?

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-v6

Where can I get High-stock old versions ?

I'm trying to get high-stock version 6 and I don't see it listed.

Answer (score 0):

This format can be used to get older versions:

https://code.highcharts.com/stock/6.1.1/highstock.js